# Export code block names in cweb or noweb style?

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

When writing a literate program in Org mode, exporting is analogous to weaving in earlier literate programming tools such as cweb or noweb. Those tools would add a code block name to the woven (exported) output. In Org mode, it would look something like this:

Org file:

```
#+NAME: mycodeblock
#+BEGIN_SRC language
[Source code here]
#+END_SRC
```

Exported output:

```
<mycodeblock>=
[Source code here]
```

I am wondering if there is any support in Org mode for exporting names of code blocks in this style. If not, is there any way to at least output the name of the code block as a label of some kind?

I have seen hints that names of code blocks can be exported, but I have failed to find the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with:

```
;; template used to export the body of code blocks
(setq org-babel-exp-code-template
      ;; (concat "\n=%name=:\n"
              org-babel-exp-code-template)
      ;; )
)
```

Though, that's not as nice as the results of NuWeb / NoWeb; see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-12/msg00170.html for a comparison of them vs Org (though the PDF links aren't accessible anymore).

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a per-file/per-project basis?