# Show the name of a code block in org-mode, when export?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

With org-mode, I'd like to export the name of a code black when exporting the code block.

For example,

```
#+NAME:code-segment-1
#+BEGIN_SRC javascript 
  var x = 5;
#+END_SRC

#+NAME:code-segment-2
#+BEGIN_SRC javascript 
  var y = 2;
#+END_SRC

#+NAME:assembly
#+BEGIN_SRC javascript :noweb yes :tangle "./assembly.js"
    <<code-segment-1>>
    <<code-segment-2>>
    return x + y;
#+END_SRC
```

I'd like the export looks like:

```
code-segment-1:
    var x = 5;

code-segment-2:
    var y = 2;

assembly:
    var x = 5;
    var y = 2;
    return x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Export code block names in cweb or noweb style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073612/export-code-block-names-in-cweb-or-noweb-style), with minor correction and verification, here is the solution:

```
(setq org-babel-exp-code-template
         (concat "\n=%name=:\n"
              org-babel-exp-code-template)
               )
```

It will produce the expected block names as desired above.

Answer (score 0):

When you export to LaTeX and use the `minted` package, then you can have the code block named with the `#+name` field with the following solution:

```
(setq org-babel-exp-code-template
         (concat "\n#+ATTR_LATEX: :options label=%name\n"
              org-babel-exp-code-template)
               )
```